# Unable to center CSS div center of computer screen

Tags: html, css

I create a main login div which show middle of screen always. But I have 2 more div. which 'one' is show above the login div and 'second' is below of login div.

My login div is show very good middle of screen but two div which was above and below of login div is not show proper. Why? Anyone help me how I fix that.

**MY CODE IS**

```css
.myLogindiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.myAbovediv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.myBelowdiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myAbovediv">Above Div Test</div>
<div class="myLogindiv">Login Div Test</div>
<div class="myBelowdiv">Below Div Test</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what is the issue and how do you want the output

Comment: First your css is about `class` not `id`
Second because these div overlap

Comment: I would suggest using Bootstrap 4 grids instead of doing your own custom CSS. Bootstrap will take care of centering the divs and arranging them.

Comment: `id` by mistake. I has been updated my question code.

Comment: @Arjit Because these div are overlap. You need to change the position between them

Comment: @codeinprogress please help here not bootstrap, bcz I have not knowledge of bootstrap

Comment: wrap these three div in single div and make align that parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap those divs in a container and apply CSS styling on that container, combining positioning with CSS `transform` to align it nicely in the middle.

```css
#loginContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="loginContainer">
  <div class="myAbovediv">Above Div Test</div>
  <div class="myLogindiv">Login Div Test</div>
  <div class="myBelowdiv">Below Div Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in div and use style to `wrap` div

```css
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="myAbovediv">Above Div Test</div>
    <div class="myLogindiv">Login Div Test</div>
     <div class="myBelowdiv">Below Div Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell for more help

Comment: Thank you @לבני מלכה, I don't know what is your username or name bcz I don't know this language but your answer was really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I unable to scroll in mobile format. Causes my some text is cut In moobMle ver. How 2 I fix

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that with 1 div:

Use the below:

```css
.mydiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
 <p>Above Div Test</p>
 <p>Login Div Test</p>
<p>Below Div Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this bullet proof snippet:

```
.your-class {
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Taken from: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

You have written the same CSS for the all of the divs, you haven't identified them uniquely so use ID's instead of classes.

Add one wrapper to these divs and make it centre to body.

Your code should be like:

```
<style>
   .demo{
      position:absolute;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
   }

   .demo > div{
     display:block;
   }
</style>

Html code:

    <div class="demo">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if i sound your question in right sense.

```css
.myLogindiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.myAbovediv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -75px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.myBelowdiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myAbovediv">Above Div Test</div>
<div class="myLogindiv">Login Div Test</div>
<div class="myBelowdiv">Below Div Test</div>
```

Comment: Don't post code only answers. Please go ahead and add an explaination.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers so far seem to rely on older techniques for centering, which isn't necessarily bad.

I'm adding my solution below which utilises flex-box layout to centre the div perfectly without having to rely on any random numbers/pixels which can feel odd in your CSS.

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrap div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="myAbovediv">Above Div Test</div>
  <div class="myLogindiv">Login Div Test</div>
  <div class="myBelowdiv">Below Div Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Flexbox will make sure the different areas stay in the correct place, no matter the screen size. You could also look at CSS Grids if you like.

**Try this**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  /* This is just 200px for the example, you can change this */
  height: 200px;
}

.myLogindiv {
  flex: 1;
}

.myAbovediv {
  flex: 1;
}

.myBelowdiv {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="myAbovediv">Above Div Test</div>
  <div class="myLogindiv">Login Div Test</div>
  <div class="myBelowdiv">Below Div Test</div>
</div>
```

If you're worried about browser support you can check it out at [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)